# Vue JS/Vuex - Call to edit user not saving

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, put, vuejs3

I'm trying to make an api call that allows me to edit a single user. The issue that I'm experiencing is that despite the call being successful (and no errors appearing), the changes are not saving. Can someone kindly guide me as to what I'm doing wrong exactly, please? I feel that I'm missing a function that allows me to save the changes after I make the call, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about this.

Edit user details:

```
setup() {
    const store = vuexStore;
    const adminId = router.currentRoute.params.adminId;

    /** Edit **/
    function editUser(formData) {
      formData.adminId = adminId;
      editAdminAccount(formData).then(response => {
        if (response) {
          redirectUserTo(ROUTE_NAMES_ADMIN.ADMIN_ACCOUNTS);
          saveUserChanges(formData);
        }
      })
    }

    // Action
    function editAdminAccount(data) {
      return store.dispatch(UPDATE_ADMIN_ACCOUNT, data);
    }

    getSelectedAdmin(adminId);
    const selectedAdmin = computed(() => store.getters.getSelectedAdmin);

    function getSelectedAdmin(adminId) {
      return store.dispatch(GET_ADMIN_BY_ID, adminId)
    }

    return {
      editUser,
      selectedAdmin,
    }
  }
```

Actions:

```
updateAdminAccount({commit}, payload) {
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('email', payload.email)
    formData.append('name', payload.name)
    formData.append('password', payload.password);

    return apiHandler.put(`user/admin/${payload.adminId}`, formData, apiHandler.getAuthHeader()).then(response => {
      return !!apiHandler.isSuccess(response.status);
    }).catch(error => {
      commit(SET_API_ERROR, error);
    });
  },
```

Comment: If the API call does not throw any error, what is the response code? Is it 200? If it is 200, check your controller because, the request could be passing through it without doing anything? Really check your controller code because that's where the saving is done. Add a log line in your controller to check if the request has arrived your controller.

Comment: @Ndianabasi I am indeed getting a response code of 200. But I didn't quite get the part where you mention the controller. Where exactly do I check this?

Comment: Which backend are you using?

Comment: @Ndianabasi I'm not really working with the backend so I wouldn't really know. However when I test it through postman it works fine, so from my understanding I must have something wrong from my front end code.

Comment: Okay. Check the request method used in postman vs the "put" request used here.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe check what the api call is returning with some console.logs to be sure of the data that is sent back.

Nevertheless, do not have to work with formdata, you can send your query items directly :

```js
updateAdminAccount({commit}, payload) {
    return apiHandler.put(`user/admin/${payload.adminId}`, payload, apiHandler.getAuthHeader())
    .then(response => !!apiHandler.isSuccess(response.status))
    .catch(error => commit(SET_API_ERROR, error));
  }
```

You also should edit the user directly after the api call in the action, and not from the template. So that the logic is kept at one place :

```js
updateAdminAccount({commit}, payload) {
    return apiHandler.put(`user/admin/${payload.adminId}`, payload, apiHandler.getAuthHeader())
    .then(response => {
      if (!!apiHandler.isSuccess(response.status)) {
        commit('UPDATE_ADMIN', payload) // payload or response.data depending if api is returning edited object
      }
      return !!apiHandler.isSuccess(response.status)
    })
    .catch(error => commit(SET_API_ERROR, error));
  }
```